# Wordpress Cron Job Counting Up and Not Down

Tags: wp-cron

I'm having a strange problem in which a WP Cron Job is counting "up" and not "down". Thus the job never runs. What I mean exactly should be clear from these outputs:

> [19-Sep-2013 23:33:51 UTC] next sync: 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds
>   [19-Sep-2013 23:34:01 UTC] next sync: 0 hours, 0 minutes, 10 seconds
>   [19-Sep-2013 23:36:35 UTC] next sync: 0 hours, 2 minutes, 44 seconds
>   [19-Sep-2013 23:36:42 UTC] next sync: 0 hours, 2 minutes, 51 seconds
>   [19-Sep-2013 23:37:39 UTC] next sync: 0 hours, 3 minutes, 48 seconds
>   [19-Sep-2013 23:37:40 UTC] next sync: 0 hours, 3 minutes, 49 seconds

Here is the code that sets the cron job:

```
function add_scheduled_interval( $schedules) {
    $schedules['minutes_5'] = array('interval'=> 5*60, 'display'=>'Once 5 minutes');
    $schedules['minutes_10'] = array('interval'=> 10*60, 'display'=>'Once 10 minutes');

return $schedules;
}
add_filter('cron_schedules', 'add_scheduled_interval');

function podio_plugin_activate() {
    // Set up cron jobs for data integration
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'minutes_10', 'podio_plugin_sync' );
}
```

In the wordpress settings, the timezone is set to UTC+0. I've tried setting it to something else and saving; then setting back and saving again. Then I have deactivated and reactivated the cron job. Same results each time.

I've looked around on the web and not been able to find anyone else reporting such a problem. Does anyone have any clues/ideas?

Comment: Probably not the cause of your problem, but note that [regarding the hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) (podio_plugin_sync): "For some reason there seems to be a problem on some systems where the hook must not contain underscores or uppercase characters."

Comment: Good to now thanks. I suspect that is not the cause, as the same hook name works on other versions of the site, i.e. dev versions. Seems to be somethign particular to his install. But I'd like to avoid reinstalling.